# Try monad for kotlin

Tags: java, functional-programming, monads, kotlin

Java 8 didn't provide Try monad. Which is useful for exception handling in functional style.

**Is there any ready implementation in kotlin? or shall i implement one?**

Comment: Are you asking whether someone else needs such a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since kotlin 1.3 you can use [runCatching](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run-catching.html)

Comment: One concern I have about `runCatching` is that it catches `Throwable` rather than `Exception`, so it also catch any subclass of java.lang.Error` too. This in my eyes is not ideal as it can hide the actual source of an error and the JVM is unusable after one of these.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no Try monad in Kotlin standard library. I'm just learning FP, but i think [sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#sealed-classes) is what you needed to implement Try monad yourself. Also there are some libraries: [Result](https://github.com/kittinunf/Result) and [funKTionale](https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale/wiki/Either).

**Upd.** Feb 2018

Now [funKTionale](https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale/wiki/Either) and [Kategory](https://github.com/Kategory/Kategory) merged into [arrow](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow) library, which has [Try](http://arrow-kt.io/docs/datatypes/try/) monad.